# How can I execute JavaScript using <s:property/> tag

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, struts2

I am just wanted to execute my script which is stored in database using `<s:property>` tag.
It is just showing JavaScript as a plain text on the screen but browser is not executing it as a script. How can I execute stored JavaScript using `<s:property/>` tag?

Comment: please provide some source code

Comment: I'm not a Struts developer, but I'm guessing it is rendering the value as text, escaping it to prevent security problems. Figure out how to make Struts output the data as raw HTML and you'll be fine. Just make sure the data is sanitized somewhere; if this is user entered data I would highly recommend not outputting it raw and telling users they can't use <script> tags.

Comment: Perfectly valid question which includes *the shortest code necessary to reproduce problem in the question itself*. :)

Answer (score 1):

By default `<s:property>` tag escapes HTML/XML/JavaScript, which is good thing by the way. To turn it off set `escapeJavaScript` and `escapeHtml` attributes to `false`.

```
<s:property escapeJavaScript="false" escapeHtml="false" />
```